# question based on installer

Tags: java

How to make an installer for java application in mac
what are the different steps  for it

Comment: What has this got to do with the iphone-sdk (as tagged) ?

Comment: Do you know that you can (and should) mark answers as accepted by clicking the check mark immediately below their score?

Comment: and have you even noticed those triangular shaped "thingies" on the left side of answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search I got [this](http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/). I think that may help you.